# My own Nameserver wont resolve domain

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, nameserver, dyndns

What I want to do is to make my domain name resolve using my own nameservers.

I got 3 VPSes, all running debian and a domain name, mydomain.com

2 VPS are nameservers and 1 is a webserver.

At my registrar i've put my domain name to DNS only and changed the nameservers to my two own nameservers.

On my first nameserver I've installed Bind9 and configured as follows.

named.conf.local

```
zone"mydomain.com" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.zone";
};

zone "x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.zone

```
mydomain.com. IN SOA ns3.mydomain.com. admin.mydomain.com. (
2006071801
28800
3600
604800
38400)

mydomain.com. IN NS ns3.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com. IN NS ns4.mydomain.com.
www           IN A  1.2.3.4 //my third VPS which is a webserver
ns3           IN A  x.x.x.x //this nameserver ip, should it be localhost?
ns4           IN A  x.x.x.x //my 2nd VPS nameserver ip
@             IN A 1.2.3.4
```

/etc/bind/zones/rev.x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa

```
@ IN SOA ns3.mydomain.com. admin.mydomain.com. (
  2006071801; 
  28800; 
  604800; 
  604800; 
  86400); 

IN NS ns3.mydomain.com.
2 IN PTR mydomain.com
```

When i run nslookup www.mydomain.com
the response is

```
Server: x.x.x.x //which points to the neighbourhood of my VPS provider
Address: x.x.x.x#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.mydomain.com
Address: x.x.x.x //this is the actual ip of my VPS webserver
```

So it seems to be working? I can't resolve via my webbrowser, am I just waiting for propagation or is there somethings missing?

Thanks in advance for any help or insightful advice.

Comment: What's the domain? Can't really check for DNS brokenness if I don't know what to look for :)

Comment: epnddns.com is the domain :)

Comment: I edited my post to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: You should probably delete the whole in-addr.arpa stuff. Most VPS providers do not delegate you this tree so it's useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ip.seveas.net/dnsgraph/png/www.epnddns.com/?skip_.=on&show_A=Show

http://ip.seveas.net/dnsgraph/png/epnddns.com/?skip_.=on&show_A=Show

So ns3 is working correctly, but ns4 is not responding. You also forgot to add an A record for the domain. Something like:

```
@           IN A  x.x.x.x //my third VPS which is a webserver
```

The @ means: the domain, not a subdomain of it.

Comment: So basiclly i need to add `@ IN A x.x.x.x` so I have a `www IN A 1.2.3.4` and `@ IN A 1.2.3.4` record? Also fixing the ns4 server, gimme a sec :)

Comment: Okay I edited my inital post to reflect my change with the @ record. I copied my settings to ns4, restarted bind and the nslookup gives me the same result as ns3 now. Does things seem correct now?

Comment: All looks ok now :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the help and that webpage it looks rather helpful, it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, for a list of online tools to test your DNS zone, see http://www.bortzmeyer.org/tests-dns.html